# MYSQL connection to C# window application

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

I am going to make a smaill application with c# .net 2.0 here I have to connect the Mysql server i am trying many tutorial but fail

I am using

```
string constr = "Server=11.22.33.123;Port=3306;Database=bfcerin_ad;" + 
                "Uid=<user id here>;Pwd=<password here>;pooling=false;";
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr);

con.Open();
```

I have tried twice my user name and password is fine but getting access denied from Server

I am able to connect to the localhost mysql with this code but not remote mysql server

Comment: You probably need to configure your remote MySQL to accept remote DB connections. There are plenty of articles on Google which explain how to do this. If you can connect to localhost then your connection string and connection methodology are clearly sound.

Comment: Er.... Publishing what looks like real username/password/IP is a really bad idea

Comment: @MarcGravell how can we possibly protect our connection string?

Comment: What is the exact exception message?

Comment: @John not sure I understand the question, but "not posting them to public websites" would be a good start. I've don't some low-level cleansing to protect our care-free user

Comment: @MarcGravell this not completely right user name and password just for look like real

Comment: @levib Please provide me the information how could I do that i think that should not be problem because I use a software livezilla that can do this may be with the help of php ect.

Comment: @CarstenSchütte this is the exact exception "Access denied for user 'bfcerin_admin'@'116.203.97.64' (using password: YES)" where 116.203.97.64 is my system ip

Comment: As levib said, check if remote connections are allowed on the MySQL server and if the user is allowed to connect from your client's ip address.

Comment: @CarstenSchütte how could i do with cpanel

Comment: hey i did it i think thanks all of you guys let me confirm fully

Comment: yes guys i did it. thanks all of you I happy :)

Comment: @DevelopmentBucket Please post what you did to solve your problem as an answer to help future users with the same problem.

Comment: @Nacereddine here is the ans "Login your cpanel and click on Remote MYSQL and then add Remote Database Access Hosts

put % for giving access to all host.
"                                                                   i can't put it in answer because lack of reputation

Comment: @DevelopmentBucket Now you have +5 reputation. If you still can't I'll post it for you.

Comment: @Nacereddine post errored me you can after 8 hours i will do then Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login your cpanel and click on Remote MYSQL and then add Remote Database Access Hosts put % for giving access to all host.